# how to Convert DateTime Now To second

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the input 15:20:30

I want to convert to seconds.

Comment: Seconds since xx date? Seconds since 00:00 today? Seconds component?

Comment: Please clarify question, DateTime.now is not 15:20:30. It has at least the date componenets. Also, you want the amount of seconds of all of hour, minutes and seconds?

Comment: Language? Technology? Are you writing c#, VB, Python, Lisp, Fortran?

Comment: You cannot convert a time to seconds, you always need a timespan (or a reference point). Do you want to convert to seconds since midnight? Or seconds since an epoch date?

Comment: Does that represent 3:20pm or 15 hours 20 minutes and 30 seconds. If it's the latter then it isn't a DateTime

Comment: @monkey_boy: you should try to clarify your question. What should be the result of the conversion?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seeing as though you haven't specified the question properly I have interpreted it to represent 15 hours 20 minutes and 30 seconds, as opposed to DateTime.Now. (Obviously this is the same as "How many seconds since midnight")

```
  TimeSpan MySpan = new TimeSpan(15, 20, 30);
  MySpan.TotalSeconds;
```

Although if you're only wanting the Seconds from the current DateTime.Now (this is not the TotalSeconds, just the current minutes seconds), just use:

```
  DateTime.Now.Second
```

Comment: Is there a DataTime.LifeStart which gets the time of the start of life 4.5 billion years (or so) ago? Seen as the question is so vague.

Comment: I have created my own DateTime object and appended a property called JesusStart that returns new DateTime(0000, 12, 25);

Comment: I have the same property. But it just raises AgentDoesNotExistError.

Answer (score 10):

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var ticks = dt.Ticks;
var seconds = ticks/TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
```

Each tick is 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: Well, that's the no of seconds since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 - are you sure that's what he wants?

Comment: Why do you assume that he asked for seconds since DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: I don't think the questioner knows what he wants :-) So the answer is deliberately incomplete --- it is all about the Ticks property and converting it to seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you really want, but if you want to compute the number of seconds from 15 hours, 20 minutes and 30 seconds you can do this:

```
Int32 GetSeconds(Int32 hours, Int32 minutes, Int32 seconds) {
  return ((hours*60) + minutes)*60 + seconds;
}
```

Comment: You can use this in any language. I know it is very simple, but my assumption is that the question also is very simple.